# Set "Display name publicly as" to be usernames by default

Tags: wp-admin, user-registration, customization, username

My WordPress site currently displays users' identifying information by their FIRSTNAME + LASTNAME.

The vast majority prefer to be known by their usernames. I've instructed how to change their "Display Name Publicly As" manually (i.e. via their User settings) but this is less than ideal.

I would like new users to be shown by their usernames as the default. Note that I want this to reflect in several plugins that refer to the "Display Name Publicly As" property.

How can this be done?

Comment: You could modify your theme to always display the username instead of anything else.

Comment: It's not only about the theme in this case, it's about a few plugins that I am using as well

Comment: That would be a helpful information for your first post, please add that information.

Comment: @flomei ok I added it

Answer (score 3):

If you want this for all future users then hook into the [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) event and update it there.

Pull the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) using [`get_userdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) and [`wp_update_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) info with the new display name.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_20160110_user_register', 10, 1 );

function wpse_20160110_user_register ( $user_id ) {

    // get the user data

    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // pick our default display name

    $display_publicly_as = $user_info->user_login;

    // update the display name

    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' =>  $display_publicly_as));
}
```

If you want to set this every login then hook [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) using [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max).

```
function wpse_20160110_wp_login ( $user_login, $user ) {

    wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $user_login));

}

add_action('wp_login', 'wpse_20160110_wp_login', PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should this code go?

Comment: Either in a plugin or functions.php, but if you put it in your theme there is a possibility it can be overwritten.

Comment: I tried the login portion and it doesn't work to change the display name

Comment: I tried the on registration action and it works!

Comment: Can you verify the hook is working first? Then make sure the data is coming in correctly. And finally that the priority is late enough? I remember this worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: How can I check if priority is late enough? (pardon me, I'm new to wordpress)

Comment: 0/1 is early. 10 is default. 99 is late, meaning runs after most hooks. You would put at 99 if another hook set that information and you want to make sure you're the last to set the metadata. But again, check that it's getting called, check the data is getting set before you worry about priority.

Comment: Cool but how do I make sure I am the last? I cant manually look through hundreds of files

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ will show you hooks and priority.

Comment: I just tested this again. updated the example to use PHP_INT_MAX which should be the last possible time to use the hook. If that doesn't work there is something else going on.

Comment: You may attach it on 'profile_update' hook, so it will be run on every update to users.

Comment: @MarcoMarsala I tried hooking on 'profile_update' and got an infinite loop. =.= Guess because this function also updates the profile.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically set the display name both on registration and profile update, avoiding the infinite loop Betty experienced, you have to check if the display name is already set as needed.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_login_as_displayname' );
add_action( 'profile_update', 'set_login_as_displayname' );

function set_login_as_displayname( $user_id )
{
    $data = get_userdata( $user_id );

    if ($data->user_login != $data->display_name) {
        wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' =>  $data->user_login));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update on registration and on profile update:

```
function set_display_name_to_first_last_name( $user_id ) {
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Construct the full name using the first name and last name.
    $full_name = trim( $user_info->first_name . ' ' . $user_info->last_name );

    // If the constructed full name is not empty and it's different from the current display name, update it.
    if ( ! empty( $full_name ) && $full_name !== $user_info->display_name ) {
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $full_name ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'set_display_name_to_first_last_name' );
add_action( 'profile_update', 'set_display_name_to_first_last_name' );
```

To update current users (run once):

```
function update_existing_users_display_names() {
    // Fetch all users
    $users = get_users();

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        // Construct the full name using the first name and last name.
        $full_name = trim( $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name );

        // If the constructed full name is not empty and it's different from the current display name, update it.
        if ( ! empty( $full_name ) && $full_name !== $user->display_name ) {
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $full_name ) );
        }
    }
}

// Call the function to perform the update.
update_existing_users_display_names();
```